# How to spy on a service function that calls another service which returns a promise - typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, angular-services

Parent Service:

```
module proj.Stuff {
  export class ParentService {
    //...properties, constructor, etc

    public refreshStuff(id: number) {
      this.childService
        .getStuff(id)
        .then((response) => this.stuff = response);
      }
   }
}
```

Child service:

```
module proj.Stuff {
  export class ChildService{
    //... properties, constructor, etc

    public getStuff(id: number) {

      var request: IPromise<any> = this.$http.get(
      ChildService.apiUrlBase + "getStuff/" + id
      );

      return request
       .then(response => {
         return response.data.value;
      }, response => {
        this.$log.error("unable to get...");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Tests for the parent service:

```
describe("ParentService", () => {

  // (property declarations omitted for brevity)

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(["$provide", ($provide) => {

    var obj = {
      getStuff: (id: number) => {
        functionCalled = true;
        return {
          then: (callback) => {
            return callback(["result"]);
          }
        };
      }
    };

    $provide.value("ChildService", obj);
  }]));

  beforeEach(mock.inject((_$http_, _$log_, _$q_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _ChildService_) => {
    cService = _ChildService_;
    pService = new ParentService(cbService);
  }));

  it("can be created", () => {
    expect(pService).toBeDefined();
    expect(pService).not.toBeNull();
  });

  it("can refresh stuff", () => {
    pService.refreshStuff(1);
    expect(pService.stuff).toEqual(["result"]);
    expect(functionCalled).toBeTruthy();

    // ***** what I want to do: *****
    // expect(cService.getStuff).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I'm wondering how can I spy on cService.getStuff instead of using the 'functionCalled' boolean?

When I try to spy on it, it complains that .then isn't defined - e.g. in the first beforeEach if I try spyOn(obj, "getStuff") it doesn't like it.

The tests pass as is, but would rather spyOn instead of using the boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then` method mocks are rarely justified, Angular DI allows to use unmocked promises and to focus on unit testing.

```
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(["$provide", ($provide) => {
    // allows to inject $q, while $provide.value doesn't
    $provide.factory("ChildService", ($q) => ({
      // fresh promise on every call
      getStuff: jasmine.createSpy('getStuff').and.callFake(() => $q.when('result'))
    }));
  }]));
```

Works best with [Jasmine promise matchers](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers), otherwise routine promise specs should be involved:

```
var result;
...then((_result) => { result = _result; })
$rootScope.$digest();
expect(result)...
```

Comment: implementing that I get 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'jasmine.createSpy("getStuff").and.callFake')... seems to be the recurring problem when doing .and.returnValue or and.callThrough on these, it says undefined

Comment: @mapleafman Check the console for stack trace and other errors. There's nothing wrong with the spy itself, http://plnkr.co/edit/SXV9Q3Xr4AwyqGbpbv78?p=preview